# How to use Microdata in React+Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, microdata

When I add `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"` to `h1`, I get this error:

> Type '{ children: string; itemscope: true; itemtype: string; }' is not
>   assignable to type
>   'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>,
>   HTMLHeadingElement>'.   Property 'itemscope' does not exist on type
>   'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>,
>   HTMLHeadingElement>'

```html
<h1 itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">Amasia</h1>
```

How to use Microdata in React+Typescript?

Comment: [React itself supports this, as of version 16](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#support-for-custom-dom-attributes). The issue is with the TypeScript definitions, it seems.

Answer (score 3):

For React, it is case Sensitive. Pay attention to: `itemScope` and `itemType` spelling

```
<div itemScope itemType={"http://schema.org/Product"}>{...}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant, but this works:

```js
// foo.d.ts
declare namespace React {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
        itemscope?: boolean;
        itemtype?: string;
    }
}
// app.tsx
function foo(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <h1 itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
            Amasia
        </h1>
    );
}
```

Works for me (Typescript 3.4.5).

Answer (score 0):

If you use typescript you should write like this

```
<h1 itemScope itemType={"http://schema.org/Product"}>{...}</h1>
```